# What does this star icon mean on Genshin Impact's minimap?

Tags: genshin-impact

Sometimes it shows up randomly on my minimap when I'm moving around, sometimes it seems like it's been there for a while. I have no clue what this symbol means -- there's no legend to tell me what it means, and the main map doesn't show them.

[image]

Sometimes it's not clear what exactly it's trying to indicate, for example:

[image]

I'm facing the star icon, the fov is pointed towards it, but there's nothing on the screen

Answer (score 17, accepted):

These are the collectible items which you can turn into the Statues of the Seven.

They are different depending on the region you are in.

- Mondstadt - [Anemoculus](https://genshin-impact.fandom.com/wiki/Anemoculus) (Small blue winged orb)
- Liyue - [Geoculus](https://genshin-impact.fandom.com/wiki/Geoculus) (Small orange crystal)

You can gather them and then devote them to any statue you find for increased stamina, adventure exp and other rewards

Sometimes they are hidden, and might require smashing rocks, exploding something or climbing up trees etc.

The example given in the question, I would attack the three piled rocks with a claymore.

Comment: FYI I recognize this spot as being an Anemoculus I found yesterday, and it is indeed hidden behind the pile of rocks that you can see the top of in the picture.

Comment: I also recently discovered that if you use Element Sight, it will highlight the smashable rocks orange indicating you can do something with it

Answer (score 0):

The star icon is for the treasure you can get like chests or something. It is probably above the cliff.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade, and thanks for answering! Could I please ask you to find some evidence? Right now there's nothing really to "back up" your claim, and please note that we are not a forum and we would like all users to put their best effort into formulating great questions and answers.